# Two post notices on same answer

Tags: bug

Two mods added the same post notice to [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30208/do-uv-furnace-filters-kill-germs-and-reduce-allergens/30228#30228) at the same time.

The result was a duplicate post notice.

> [image]

I have since removed the notice (they both came off with one operation) and re-added it to fix.

Comment: I already reported it directly to the core team.

Comment: So, two mods posted bug reports at the same time too?

Comment: Blame it on software engineers employees ;)